# Exclusion in regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have a strings like:

> { "_id" : ObjectId( "4ebb9544e4b097b7e6617e1c" ), "_class" :

I need a strings like:

> { "_id" : "4ebb9544e4b097b7e6617e1c", "_class" :

How to make this conversion in java?

Comment: Well, replace `ObjectId(x)` with `x` (hint: use a "capture group"). Simple enough ... as far as "simple" ever is for a regular expression. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really know the exact form of the string, and the object-ID will always be hex like that, you can just do:

```
s = s.replaceAll("ObjectId\\( ([^)]+) \\)", "$1");
```

Comment: You are suffering from my problem as well. If you have a ) inside the other before the final ) your regex fails.

Comment: @FailedDev: I don't think that's possible: this object-ID is obviously hex, so I assume that all object-IDs will be. (My answer was explicit about that assumption.) I believe the problem that Vladimir had with your answer was that it could remove a `)` elsewhere in the string, rather than that it could remove a `)` inside the object-ID. (Vladimir, care to step in and clarify?)

Comment: @ruakh You're correct. The data inside ObjectId can't contain stuff like '('. My problem was to remove ObjectId() wrapping and do not touch  other bracket symbols. Sorry for I haven't provided more detailed input.